# Having tmux load by default when a zsh terminal is launched

Tags: terminal, zsh, tmux

My current workflow is:

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to launch a new terminal window. That starts a new zsh terminal.
2. Type `tmux` to start tmux.

How can I have tmux load by default with a new terminal window?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There are at least two ways:

1. Write something like

   ```
   if [ "$TMUX" = "" ]; then tmux; fi
   ```

   at the beginning of `~/.zshrc`. Note the conditional test to a possible loop when `tmux` spawns its own `zsh`.
2. Modify terminal launching command to something like

   ```
   xterm -e tmux
   ```

I prefer the second way, because sometimes I need to launch a terminal without `tmux` (for example when I need to reconnect to an existing session).

Comment: Or have different shortcuts for `xterm -e tmux` and plain `xterm`.

Comment: Yes, actually I meant it under "I prefer the second way" =)

Comment: Executing `tmux` at the end of `.zshrc` will cause an endless loop of zsh starting tmux starting zsh starting tmux ...

Comment: How would one go about "modifying terminal launching command"?

Comment: @eoinoc it depends on your environment. For example, I'm using awesome wm, therefore I just need to modify string in my config file. In kde you need to edit hotkeys. And so on.

Comment: @Rush Great, I was able to do it with `gnome-conf` http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41442/how-do-i-edit-the-terminal-launch-command-in-linux-mint

Comment: I am really sorry that I down-voted this answer by a misclick - would be nice if down vote can to removed/reset.

Comment: In my setup, the $TMUX variable is not empty even if I'm not inside a tmux session. Executing ```echo $TMUX``` returns ```/tmp//tmux-1000/default,1647,2```. Does anybody know why that is or how to adjust the script to make @rush's solution work under these circumstances?

Answer (score 23):

There is actually a default plugin `tmux` for `oh_my_zsh`.

Add it to your plugins list then set `ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART=true` in your `.zshrc`

For more reference, go [here](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/tmux)

Comment: Out of curiosity are you using that now? Doesnt work for me. Have that env set and it doesnt start. tmux definitely added to plugin array,

Comment: you have to add the `ZSH...=...` assignment before the line `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`, from https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/3676#issuecomment-77806736

Comment: also add tmux to the list of your plugins in `.zshrc`:

`plugins=(... tmux)`

Answer (score 16):

add it to your `.zshrc`

```
if [ -z "$TMUX" ]
then
    tmux attach -t TMUX || tmux new -s TMUX
fi
```

then tmux will automatically connect to a session called **TMUX** when you launch your terminal.

Answer (score 8):

Be careful with the `echo tmux >> ~/.zshrc` solution though, I remember
that simply throwing a `bash` in a `.cshrc` file caused me trouble over SSH.

IIRC the problem occurred with non-interactive shells, so you should test for that.

```
case $- in *i*)
  if [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then exec tmux; fi;;
esac
```

Comment: You're missing a space between `"` and `]`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
if [ -z $TMUX ]; then; tmux -t TMUX || tmux new -s TMUX; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

My compromise is to automatically start `tmux` if no sessions are running.

This way, only the first terminal window starts tmux. A following windows do not start `tmux` and you can decide to attach to a session or to not use tmux at all there.

To do so add the following at the beginning of `~/.zshrc`:

```bsh
if [[ ! $(tmux list-sessions) ]]; then 
  tmux
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "tmux" to your .zshrc file, which gets executed every time you start zsh. The quick way:

```
echo tmux >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: The thing with this, is that it starts a new session in every new instance and it bloats tmux with sessions that you've never exited (also tmux will complain about it). Not a good solution.