# How do I edit the terminal launch command in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal

In Linux Mint (Debian-based) how can I edit what the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> launches?

For example, I would like to issue `gnome-terminal` with the `--maximize` option, and to have it launch tmux instantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the `/desktop/gnome/applications/terminal/exec` key in GConf (using `gconf-editor`), which is described as "*the default terminal application to use for applications that require a terminal*".

Alternatively, I propose a little more flexible solution: if you use Compiz, you can use the `Commands` plugin to define keyboard shortcuts for your own commands.
This way, you can keep the default shortcut to launch a windowed terminal, and define an other shortcut for a fullscreen terminal.

(Sidenote: in the Compiz configuration tool, you can change directly the terminal command and shortcut in the `Gnome Compatibility` plugin.)

Comment: From your answer, I was able to do this also from the command line: `gconftool-2 --type string --set /desktop/gnome/applications/terminal/exec "gnome-terminal --maximize -e tmux"`.

Comment: For Gnome 3-based installations, it seems `gconf-editor` is being phased out. User `dconf-editor` instead. http://askubuntu.com/questions/122039/dconf-editor-and-gconf-editor . And user `gsettings` instead of `gconftool-2` at the command line.

Comment: This certainly works (when using dconf-editor instead) for the expressed purpose, which is what I wanted to use it for (to get it to launch the terminal window maximized when using the launch terminal keyboard shortcut). However, this causes the right click menu item "Open in Terminal" to stop working. I am guessing the extra --maximize argument I added is interfering with the additional arguments passed by that menu item. Any way to fix that or see what command is being run?

Answer (score 5):

1. Install `dconf-editor`

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
   ```
2. Open dconf-editor

   ```
   $ dconf-editor
   ```
3. Navigate to the terminal key

   ```
   org->cinnamon->desktop->applications->terminal
   ```
4. Change the key to the terminal you want

   ```
   Name=exec => Value=konsole
   ```

*EXTRA:*

Remember to install that terminal you want by default first. (Obviously)

```
sudo apt-get install konsole
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer in 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Even easier is by just:

Add Terminator

Click "Menu" > Search "Terminator" > Right-Click "Add to Favourites"

Remove default terminal in favourites (Cinnamon):

Click "Menu" > Search "Terminal" > Right-Click "Remove from Favourites"