# Ranger file manager as the singleton instance on shell startup

Tags: zsh, startup, ranger

**Problem**:
I use **zsh** and added to its config file a line of launching **ranger** on startup.

*.zshrc*

```
# A few other settings and commands.
ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART="true"
plugins=(tmux ...)

source ranger
```

Due to it every newly opened(mostly in **tmux**) zsh runs ranger.

**Expectation**:
Lauch a ranger process only if there is no running one.

Something like looks as follow:

```
if [[ ! -v RANGER_RUNNIG ]]; then
   export RANGER_RUNNING="true"
   source ranger
fi
```

Comment: this doesn't seem logical on multiple levels – why do you start zsh when you actually want to start ranger?

Comment: I don't start it, it's my default shell. A point is when i run tmux its first pane contains a ranger process and if i open more panes they also run it what i would like to disable.

Moreover, if i open a subshell from a ranger process it inherits such a behaivor.

Comment: would you not rather want your tmux to open a ranger in the first pane, and for any other pane, start a zsh?

Comment: your `export` approach cannot work, because environment variables are only passed to children (i.e., processes started by a process), not along "siblings" (i.e., processes that were started by the same process, in your case tmux)

Comment: Well, as i use tmux zsh plugin i don't see a way to extend it by running tmux on startup only once with a custom command, it's ranger in my case. But the idea sounds good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the solution through modifying what zsh does on every new shell sounds a bit complicated. Instead, simply start your `tmux` with the program that you want to show in the first pane:

```bsh
tmux new-session ranger
```

When you manually add further panes, they will just start the default shell.

You can also prepare a whole bunch of panes. For example, to start with a layout of

```
┌────────────┬───────────┐
│            │    zsh    │
│            │           │
│  ranger    ├───────────┤
│            │    zsh    │
│            │           │
└────────────┴───────────┘
```

you could just

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
# e.g. /usr/local/bin/my_tmux
# or just ~/bin/mt, to make your typing easier 
# (assuming /home/r45i/bin is part of $PATH)
#

# check we're not running within tmux
if [ -z "$TMUX" ]
then
  # start a detached session
  tmux new-session -d ranger
  # split the window horizontally
  tmux split-window -h
  # split the freshly created vertically
  tmux split-window -v
  # attach to the session
  tmux attach-session -d
fi
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion. But if you take a look at tmux plugin code you probably will get to an issue that it's incompatible to use the plugin env `ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART` and launch tmux with the `tmux new-session -d ranger`  command. What do you think about it?

Code of the plugin is here https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/plugins/tmux/tmux.plugin.zsh#L20

Comment: sorry, must admit I don't have the time to go through that. Feels like a programming problem, someone at stackoverflow might be able to help rather rapidly!

Comment: Got it. Anyway, i'm going to work it out and after, if find a solution, get back to here to extend your answer. Thx.

Comment: I decided to drop **tmux plugin** off, it brings too much pain =) This snippet https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355206/467276 fits more than others to my case. Now i added a line `tmux new ranger` inside the condition from the snippet to the end of `.zshrc`.